# What is $2^{\log (n) + 1} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Is $$2^{\log n+ 1 }= 2\times 2^{\log n}?$$

Because when we add the powers in $2 ^{\log n}\times 2^1$, we get $2^{\log n+ 1} $.

Am I right ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: if log has base $2$ then $2^{log n} = n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you are right.**

It is obvious that $$a^{\alpha + \beta} = a^{\alpha}\times a^{\beta} $$ (*On a side note, think when it is not true.*)

Hope it helps.